# Additional Drivers crashes in Software Properties

Tags: drivers, 13.10

I'm trying to use Software Properties (software-properties-gtk) to install nvidia drivers. When I open the Additional Drivers tab it just says "searching for additional drivers..." and then Apport comes up telling me Ubuntu has had an internal error. The available additional drivers never show up, the list just stays empty.

When I run software-properties-gtk from the terminal I get the following output right before the crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py", line 634, in <lambda>
    return (lambda data: callback(*data), user_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1323, in show_drivers
    (overall_status, icon, drivers) = self.gather_device_data(self.devices[device])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 1277, in gather_device_data
    description = base_string.format(base_description=description, licence=licence)
KeyError: 'license'
```

Is this a known bug? Can I fix it?

Comment: Seems to be a bug in 13.10, no fix for the moment, see launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1268134

Comment: Forgot to say - I can reproduce it on my setup.

Comment: That's my bug report, so it might not be very wide spread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py and correct that typo! Find "licence" and replace it with "license"!

That did the trick for me :)

Comment: I find 6 occurences of "licence" and those seem to be consistent. Did you change all of them?

Comment: Yes i changed all of them and then the additional drivers tab works again.

Comment: No fix for this yet it seems. Its affected 3 out of 4 different machines for me so far. The common denominator i've spotted so far is the crash occurs whenever options to use proprietary graphics drivers are provided, which should affect A LOT of people. Correcting the typo fixed the problem in all 3 cases...

Comment: The fix is out since a while, and so, this shouldn't be an issue for updated systems at all anymore. See bug 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1319257

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it will be easier for you to solve your particular problem if you install *jockey-gtk*. jockey-gtk will make it easier for you to open Additional Drivers. jockey-gtk is available in the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 13.10. Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk
```

---

1. Search for *jockey-gtk* in the Dash.
2. Click on the Additional Drivers icon to open **Additional Drivers**.
3. A little Additional Drivers window will open with an orange bar moving back and forth. It will start searching for additional drivers. Let it search for additional drivers for at least  3 minutes.
4. Close Additional Drivers from the Launcher or if you can't close Additional Drivers from the Launcher, kill the Additional Drivers processes (software-properties-gtk and jockey-gtk) in the System Monitor.
5. Open Additional Drivers again. This time the available additional drivers may show up in Additional Drivers.

Comment: I guess I spelled that out wrong: There are no search results at all when typing "Additional Drivers" in the Dash. So I'm stuck at step 2 in your answer.

Comment: I actually didn't know Ask Ubuntu had a limit on comments, but sure I've deleted some of them! I really appreciate your help, and I'm sorry for the confusion about which version I'm on.

Comment: Had the same problem with software-properties-gtk crashing on additional drivers search in 13.10. With jockey it worked. Thanks karel.

Comment: Forgot to say - i worked for me with jockey-kde. Which means youll get a lot of kde-packages installed too, but its a workaround until a fix is available.